# onGpsStatusChanged NOT firing for GpsStatus.Listener

Tags: android, gps, android-location

Would like to listen to **gps availability**. Followed [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html). However, `onGpsStatusChanged` was not fired even when I disabled/enabled gps. Tried on multiple phones. Also, looked into related stackoverflow Qns such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799337/ongpsstatuschangedint-event-is-never-called), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198363/gpsstatus-listener-not-firing-on-network-status-changes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755880/how-to-test-gps-status). However met with no success. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Code Snippets:

**Listener**

```
Listener mGPSListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(final int event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "---onGpsStatusChanged---");
        switch (event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "GPS_EVENT_STARTED");
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                Log.d(TAG, "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX");
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                Log.d(TAG, "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED");
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                Log.d(TAG, "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "SOMETHING_ELSE");
                break;
        }


    }


};
```

**Service**

```
.....
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        Context ctx = getBaseContext();
        Log.d(TAG, "Done, " + ctx);
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)
        ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Got locManager");
        locManager.addGpsStatusListener(mGPSListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "Added -> locManager.addGpsStatusListener(mGPSListener)");
        return START_STICKY;


    }
.....
```

Could see log statements for `context`, `LocationManager`, etc. However nothing from `onGpsStatusChanged` at all.

*Edit1*
My manifest contains following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so here is my finding.

If you want `onGpsStatusChanged` of your `GpsStatus.Listener` called you need to **NOT ONLY register it to your `LocationManager` using `addGpsStatusListener` but also listen for location updates by `requestLocationUpdates`.**

As soon as I started listening to location updates by means of `requestLocationUpdates` of `LocationManager` class, I started getting gps status changes.